# Detect that Horizontal Scroll is visible or not

Tags: c++, winapi, wxwidgets

I have wxWidget application and I have created a scrolled window

```
wxScrolledWindow *pScrollingBucket = new wxScrolledWindow(this, wxID_ANY);
wxPanel* pPanel1 = new wxPanel(pScrollingBucket , wxID_ANY);
wxPanel* pPanel2 = new wxPanel(pScrollingBucket , wxID_ANY);

wxBoxSizer* pSizerHorz = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
pSizerHorz->Add(pPanel1 , 1, wxGROW|wxALL, 0);
pSizerHorz->Add(pPanel2 , 1, wxGROW|wxALL, 0);
pScrollingBucket->SetSizer(pSizerHorz);
pScrollingBucket->FitInside();
pScrollingBucket->SetScrollRate(3, 0);
```

Every thing is working as expected. On full screen there is no scroll, When I am doing resizing to small size, Scroll is comming, and getting OnSize() event handler of main window. In Onsize() I want to detect that scroll bar is visible or not.
Any help with plain Win32 API is also accepted.

Do not suggest HasScrollbar(), it only tells that window has wxHSCROLL creation flag or not.

Comment: Is it possible to derive from `wxScrolledWindow` and overwrite `wxWindow::SetScrollbar()`? The you could detect when the scrollbar is switched on and off.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plain Win32 code:

```
function IsScrollBarVisible(AWindow: HWND; AVert: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  Code: Integer;
  Info: TScrollInfo;
begin
  if AVert then Code := SB_VERT
           else Code := SB_HORZ;
  Code := SB_VERT;
  Info.cbSize := SizeOf(Info);
  Info.fMask := SIF_RANGE or SIF_PAGE;
  GetScrollInfo(AWindow, Code, Info);
  Result := (Info.nMin <> Info.nMax) and (Info.nPage <= Info.nMax);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wxScrolled::IsScrollbarShown(wxHORIZONTAL)` for this but are you sure you actually need it? It's pretty unusual to have to do things differently depending on whether the scrollbar is shown or not and you should also consider that some platforms don't show scrollbars all the time but just bring them up when the mouse hovers near the window edge.